# Duda bucle for-in en Swift

Tags: array, swift, bucle-for

Estoy intentando hacer el siguiente ejercicio en Swift:
***Crea la función `obtenerFrecuencias` que permita calcular las frecuencias de un conjunto de respuestas, números entre 0 y 9, que se guardan en un array de Int.***

Ejemplo:

```
let respuestas = [0,0,1,1,2,1,2,3,5,1,2,2,2,6]
let frec = obtenerFrecuencias(respuestas: respuestas)
print("Frecuencias: \(frec)")
Frecuencias: [2, 4, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Sé que la solución es la siguiente:

```
   func obtenerFrecuencias(respuestas: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var frecuencias = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10)
    for puntuacion in respuestas {
        frecuencias[puntuacion] += 1
    }
    return frecuencias
   }
```

Pero no entiendo la forma en la que actúa el bucle ***for-in***, debería actuar sobre los índices (en este caso llamado puntuacion) del array, por lo que para respuestas[0] devolvería 0, respuestas[1] = 0, respuesta[2] = 1... pero la ejecución de ***frecuencias[puntuacion] += 1*** no conseguiría lo deseado...
Parece ser que no se fija en el índice si no que en el valor asociado, me explico:
Por cada puntuación con valor 'i' en el array inicial, suma 1 al valor del índice 'i' en el array resultante y así sucesivamente hasta recorrer por completo el primer array. 
 Así si que se consigue lo deseado pero no sé si hay otra explicación, ni si es posible implemenarlo de esta forma...
He estado revisando la [documentación de Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) y buscado por la web pero no encuentro nada al respecto.
Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ciclo **for-in** trabaja de la siguiente manera:

```
for puntuación in respuestas {
}
```

Obtiene uno a uno los elementos de objeto que itera, en este caso en la primera vuelta puntuación valdría 0 , después 0 , luego 1 y así sucesivamente recorriendo cada elemento del array respuestas.

En la función que compartes la magia la hace el objeto frecuencias al usar el inicializador  Array(repeating: 0, count: 10) lo que realiza esta instrucción es construir un arreglo con longitud 10 cuyas posiciones tendrán el elemento inicial 0 :

Te pongo un ejemplo para mayor claridad

```
let fiveZs = Array(repeating: "Z", count: 5)
print(fiveZs)
// Prints "["Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"]"
```

En tu caso se crearía un objeto de la siguiente forma

```
var frecuencias = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Posteriormente en el ciclo **for-in** lo que hace es obtiene el primer valor de respuestas que es 0 y le indica a frecuencias acceder a ese indice y en esa posición que existe un valor de cero le incremente en 1 y así sucesivamente, en algo gráfico luciría de la siguiente forma:

```
let respuestas = [0,0,1,1,2,1,2,3,5,1,2,2,2,6]

for puntuacion in respuestas {.....
    frecuencias[0] += 1 //posición 0 vale 1
    frecuencias[0] += 1 //posición 0 vale ahora 2
    frecuencias[1] += 1 //posición 1 vale 1
    frecuencias[1] += 1 //posición 1 vale ahora 2
    frecuencias[2] += 1 //posición 2 vale ahora 1
    frecuencias[1] += 1 //posición 1 vale ahora 3
    frecuencias[2] += 1 //posición 2 vale ahora 2
    frecuencias[3] += 1 //posición 3 vale 1
    frecuencias[5] += 1 //posición 5 vale 1
    frecuencias[1] += 1 //posición 1 vale ahora 4
    frecuencias[2] += 1 //posición 2 vale ahora 3
    frecuencias[2] += 1 //posición 2 vale ahora 4
    frecuencias[2] += 1 //posición 2 vale ahora 5
    frecuencias[6] += 1 //posición 6 vale ahora 1
}.....
```

Como nunca se accede a posición 4,7, 8 y 9 del arreglo frecuencias , estas quedan en 0 y por ende nuestros valores de salida son:

```
[2, 4, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```